# radio button/checkbox in material design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, material-design

I use material design in mvc. for add radiobutton/checkbox in mvc i use this code.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(e => e.Type, 0, new { id = "hair-short1", @class="with-gap" })
@Html.Label("hair-short1", "Short")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(e => e.Type, 1, new { id = "hair-short", @class = "with-gap" })
@Html.Label("hair-short", "Short")
```

it is ok but when click submit button Type is null.

and for checkbox i use this code

```
 <input id="Diabetes" class="chk-col-red" checked="" type="checkbox">
 <label for="Diabetes">دیابت</label>
```

and in viewmodel

```
 public ActionResult Add()
  {
   ViewBag.Action = "Add";
   return View(new Referred());
  }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Add([Bind(Exclude = "Id,CreatedDateTime,CreatedUserId")]Referred model)
  {
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      model.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
      model.CreatedUserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
      _db.Referreds.Add(model);
      _db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     else
     {
     ViewBag.Action = "Add";
     Warning("لطفا صحت اطلاعات ورودی را بررسی کنید.", dismissable: true);
     return View(model);
       }
    }
```

and Model

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
  public bool? Type{ get; set; }
```

Comment: You checkbox does not have a `name` attribute so would not post back anything

Comment: Thanks, i set `name` but always return `false`

Comment: You have not shown your model or the method you are posting to.

Comment: plz see my edit.

Comment: You still have not shown your model. Is `Type` (and the `bool`) properties with public setters

Comment: Also show your updated code for the checkbox - does it also have a `value` attribute

Comment: Plz see my edit. Type is a Bool value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173515/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ar-gorgin).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use input type of radio button for material design.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked> Female
```